# Efficient way of calculating Top Frequent Values together with Top Max. values with Dataframe (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

After reading data to PySpark Dataframe. I want to find two things:

- Top 5 frequent values and their corresponding frequencies
- Top 5 distinct maximum values

I want to know **efficient way of doing it**.

**Example:**

```
Col1    |    Col2
10      |    abc
10      |    xyz
10      |    abc
90      |    xyz
10      |    abc
90      |    xyz
90      |    abc
10      |    xyz
10      |    abc
10      |    xyz
```

Result for this would be-

***For Col1,***

Top Frequent values are 10, 90 with 7, 3 frequencies respectively.
Top Maximum values are 90, 10

Similarly, for Col2. This is a very small/simple example.

**My take:**

Keeping in mind that I want to perform less and less actions.

Calculate column by column. For Col1,

```
(dataframe.groupby('Col1').count()
.withColumn('rank_count', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('count')))
.withColumn('rank_value', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('Col1')))
.filter("rank_value <= 5 or rank_count <= 5").collect())
```

Then extract final result from output of this collect.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the most frequent values in Col1,

```
    dataframe.groupby(col('Col1')).agg(count('*').alias('frequency')\
    .sort(col('frequency'),ascending=False).show(5,False)
```

For finding the top 5 distinct values in a dataframe in Col1

```
   dataframe.select('Col1').distinct().orderBy("Col1", ascending=False).show(5,False)
```

Comment: Thanks.. I thought of this way, but then I thought these will be **two actions**. Is it a good/effiecient way?...................... And Sorry, I forgot to mention, I need top 5 **distinct maximum values**. I have edited the question.

Comment: This would need two actions, but then everything else would too.